# ¿Cómo puedo lograr que mis funciones sean identificadas en la clase?

Tags: python, clase, método

Buenas tardes(días o noches),  estoy trabajando con Python en el concepto de clase y métodos. Necesito hacer un "juego" que permita al usuario interactuar con su perro. Y tengo un método que 'despierta' al perro para que el usuario lo pueda sacar a pasear.

```
class dog:
    def __init__(self, name, posx, posy):
        self.name=name
        self.posx=0
        self.posy=0
        self.awaken=False
        self.counter=0
        self.hungry=False
        def isAwaken(self):
            if(self.awaken==False):
               self.awaken=True
               return 'El perro está despierto'
```

Creo un objeto y al utilizar esta opción:

```
perro=dog('Lamar', 0,0)
print(perro.isAwaken())
```

Me arroja un error de:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-bb7891ad8131> in <module>
 28                 self.country=False
 29 perro=dog('Lamar',0,0)
 ---> 30 print(perro.isAwaken)
 AttributeError: 'dog' object has no attribute 'isAwaken'
```

Quisiera saber, para que no me ocurra más adelante. ¿Cómo solucionar este error para que así el programa reconozca el método 'isAwaken'?

Gracias.

Comment: Tienes mal la indentación. Tal como lo has escrito, la función `isAwaken()` está "metida" dentro del  método `__init__()` y por tanto no puede llamarse desde fuera. Debes desindentar esa función, para que esté al mismo nivel que `__init__()` y así sea otro método de la clase.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es con la indentación, lo trataré de describir un poco más a fondo en el código.

```
class dog:

    def __init__(self, name, posx=0, posy=0):  #  Si quieres que por defecto, posx y posy
                                               #+ define su valor dentro de los parametros
                                               #+ esperados.
        self.name = name
        self.posx = posx     #  Cambie el valor de 0 a posx y posy, de lo contrario
        self.posy = posy     #+ carece de sentido que se mande a llamar desde la
        self.awaken = False  #+ funcion __init__
        self.counter = 0
        self.hungry = False

    '''
    Tu problema esta en la indentacion de la funcion isAwaken
    ya que pusiste la funcion isAwaken dentro de __init__, 
    entonces, cada que se inicialice el objeto dog, isAwaken se cargara, 
    pero no es metodo de dog, sino una simple funcion
    dentro de otra funcion.
    '''

    def isAwaken(self):  #  Nota que la funcion isAwaken ahora ya esta indentada
                         #+ fuera de __init__
        if self.awaken == False:
            self.awaken = True
            return 'El perro esta despierto'


def main():
    fido = dog('Fido', 4, 4)
    huesos = dog('Huesos')

    print('%s esta en (%s,%s)' % (fido.name, fido.posx, fido.posy))
    print('%s esta despierto: %s' % (fido.name, fido.awaken))
    print(fido.isAwaken())

    print('')

    print('%s esta en (%s,%s)' % (huesos.name, huesos.posx, huesos.posy))
    print('%s esta despierto: %s' % (huesos.name, huesos.awaken))
    print(huesos.isAwaken())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

La ejecución resultaría en algo por el estilo.

```
$ python dog.py
Fido esta en (4,4)
Fido esta despierto: False
El perro esta despierto

Huesos esta en (0,0)
Huesos esta despierto: False
El perro esta despierto
```

Por cierto, por si sirve de algo para aclarar la notación del `print()`, usé python3.5

Si quieres revisar tu código paso a paso, te recomiendo la librería de `inspect` y la función `dir`.

Por ejemplo, si creaste tu clase `dog` tal cual, no te aparecerá listado el método `isAwaken`

```
def inspecionar():
    perro = dog('perro')

    print('Los metodos que tiene son:')
    for metodo in inspect.getmembers(perro, inspect.ismethod):
        print('metodo: '+ metodo[0])

    print('Los atributos que tiene son:')
    for atributos in inspect.getmembers(perro):
        print('Attributo: '+ atributos[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inspecionar()
```

Y al ejecutarlo mostrará:

```
$ python dog.py
Los metodos que tiene son:
metodo: __init__
Los atributos que tiene son:
Attributo: __init__
Attributo: awaken
Attributo: counter
Attributo: hungry
Attributo: name
Attributo: posx
Attributo: posy
... etc
```

Como notarás, no está `isAwaken`.